# jQuery selector to exclude parents with a specific class

Tags: jquery

I have the following query to select all `input` and `select` elements of a certain type, and I need to extend it to exclude all items whose parents have a certain class:

```
$('input,select')
        .not('[type="checkbox"],[type="radio"],[type="button"],[type="submit"]')
        .not(':parent.no-field-hint') // <-- NEED TO FIX THIS
        .on('focus', function () {
        // do something
    });
```

How can I modify the line in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic here is a little too complicated for a selector, aside from the fact there's no `:parent` selector. You could use `filter()` to achieve what you need though:

```
$('input, select').not('[type="checkbox"], [type="radio"], [type="button"], [type="submit"]').filter(function() {
  return !$(this).parent().hasClass('no-field-hint');
}).on('focus', function () {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works - just need to remove the dot in `.no-field-hint`

Answer (score 1):

Just check in your function what the parents class is:
https://jsfiddle.net/gzvbd729/

```
$(function(){
    $('input,select')
        .not('[type="checkbox"],[type="radio"],[type="button"],[type="submit"]')
        .on('focus', function () {
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('parent1')) {
            $(this).val('blaat');
        }
    });
});
```